# Configuring setup to allow hosted service to be accessible outside network?

Tags: arcgis-server, map-service, feature-service

I have services hosted on my GIS server they are being consumed in maps published to ArcGIS online and also Collector. When i am connected to my network at work, everything works perfect. However when i get off my work network, it all falls apart. I will try to access my services via AGOL or Collector only to get 'services not available. NSURL Error -10003". So somehow my services are not available out side my network

i thought by having the webaptor install on my webserver was supposed to take care of this, and make my services available, but it doesnt seem to be doing that. So what is it about my set up that is off.

Machine 1:
Windows Server 2012R | ArcGIS for server 10.3.1 | Windows Firewall is on and i have the following rules in place: Inbound - Local ports 80, 6080, 4000-4003; Remote Port: All Ports | Outbound - Local ports 80, 6080, 4000-4003; Remote Port: 80, 6080, 4000-4003

Machine 2:
Windows Server 2012R | ArcGIS webadapter 10.3.1 | Windows Firewall is on and i have the following rules in place: Inbound - Local ports 80, 6080, 4000-4003; Remote Port: All Ports | Outbound - Local ports 80, 6080, 4000-4003; Remote Port: 80, 6080, 4000-4003

So what gives why can i not access my hosted features outside my network?

Comment: So this server is accessible on the intranet, what firewall rules are protecting the intranet from the outside? Are there any other web resources that are accessible from this box?

Comment: @baens that i dont know and i would have to check with IT. is it possible that we are using another firewall other than/in addition top the windows firewall? is there a specific question i could ask IT when i take to them?

Comment: Yes, usually there is a firewall between you and the outside internet. Work with your IT folks on the process of getting that to the outside.